# How To pass data from one Page component to another page Component.?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ionic-framework

I have a crud application where i click on the delete button and it should reflect me a modal, in which i want to ensure delete or not ,while clicking on delete it should delete the data specific.

I have Tried calling it,but i don't know to pass the actual data is not getting it is reflecting me undefined.what should i do for passing the data from one component to another page modal component.

giving you stackbltiz.

while clicking on delete button after confirmation it should delete.and getting error of the undefined id.

Comment: Where is the stackbltiz URL ?

Comment: i don't know to import the data into the stackbltiz,will you guide me how to import full directory path to the stackbtliz

Comment: Share the GitHub repo of the project.

Comment: sorry ,but i don't know how to do it properly i have done it and trying to do in good way

Comment: You stackblitz project is incomplete. Looks like all the necessary components are not there.

Comment: actually i tried to complete all the component's it's show's me the error of the ngbootstrap ,how to open terminal on it..?

Comment: On the left panel, there is a dependencies section, type the library you want to install

Comment: In `form.component.ts` `src/app/welcome/welcome.service` and `'src/app/welcome/welcome.model'` is not valid import. You should be providing a valid relative import. Proper path is `'../../welcome/welcome.service'`. Now we are solving issues that are not related to the question. You should have provided the git repo.

Comment: i am extremely sorry for that issue's but i am new to it and want to learn it so sorry for your inpatient.

Comment: Which angular version you are using?

Comment: 8.0.6 updated angular is it.

Comment: b45i, can i know are you helping out..?

Answer (score 0):

You are using ng-bootstrap modal. You can open the modal using the syntax after importing the deleteModalComponent :

```
 modalOptions: NgbModalOptions;
 let modalRef = this.modal.open(DeleteModalComponent, this.modalOptions);
```

When you are in the deleteModalComponent then you can use this:

```
    modalRef.componentInstance.deleteEvent.
                    pipe(takeWhile(() => keepPvSubscription)).
                    subscribe(delete => {
                                modalRef.close();
                            },
});
```

Comment: with that type it's not happening it's giving me error of the NgbModalOptions..!

Comment: you need to import NgbModalOptions use: 

`import { NgbModalOptions } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/modal/modal-config';`